# jquery animating multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, jquery-effects

I'm trying to do the following:

I have two sets of DOM elements on a page. All elements in the first set carry the class `display-element`, and the second set of elements carry the class `edit-element`.

Now I have a button (id=`edit-button`). When I click this button, I want all the `display-elements` to fade out, and all the `edit-elements` to appear.

I naturally did:

```
$('#edit-button').click(function(){
    $('.display-element').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('.edit-element').fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

I found to my surprise that this did not work as expected. This is what happened: as soon as the first element with class `display-element` faded out, all the `edit-elements` started fading in.

Now is there any easy way (perhaps something in the documentation I missed) using which I can have all the `edit-elements` start fading in *only after all `display-elements` have faded out?*

Thanks
jrh

Comment: You're saying the display-element elements aren't fading out all at the same time?  This is what should be happening.

Comment: I'm not saying much. I understand that the behaviour I observe is the expected behavior. What I want to know is if there is some nifty jQuery API method that will help me do what I want to do (and will circumvent the behaviour I am observing right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would this happen, really? I mean, it appears, that you are starting the animations at the same time (there is only one call to `.fadeOut` after all, right?). I guess, this is because $() yields an array and when you call `.fadeOut`, jQuery iterates through the array and performs whatever it performs for each of its elements. Starting from the first. Since the callback gets "attached" to every animation, you see the visible effect of the first callback.

I guess, you could sidestep this by iterating through the array of the returned elements yourself and making sure, that you attach the callback only to the last one.

```
$('#edit-button').click(function(){
    var display_elements = $('.display-element');
    var len = display_elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
        $(display_elements[i]).fadeOut(300); // no callback
    }
    $(display_elements[len-1]).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('.edit-element').fadeIn(300);
    }); // last element - attach callback
});
```

I am sorry if the code is off, I must admit, that my javascript-fu is not very strong :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, having not found any 'nifty API method', I resolved to this:

```
$('#edit-button').click(function() {
    var displays = $('.display-element');
    var counter = 0;
    var max = displays.length;
    displays.fadeOut(300, function() {
        counter++;
        if( counter>=max ) $('.input-element').fadeIn(300);
    }
});
```

This is essentially @shylent's answer, with more 'javascript-fu' :)

Comment: Ah yes, this is certainly better :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a setTimeout on the fading in function

```
$('#edit-button').click(function(){
    $('.display-element').fadeOut(300);
setTimeout("$('.edit-element').fadeIn(300);", 300);
});
```

That javascript function will delay the trigger of the the fading in function for 300 miliseconds

Comment: this will work approximately, but ... time durations are not so reliable, especially in milliseconds..

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a similar issue and found the "step" callback option yielded the desired behavior.

> step: A function to be called after each step of the animation.

^ http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Scroll down to the demo for step usage and you'll see how it will enable you to call animate on a single object then use step to update the rest your set at each step of the animation. This way you only have one callback fired when the animation completes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with fadeToggle(), so I used your counter solution for those..

Cheers!